# Many to one mapping in Mule

Tags: mule

[image]Example I have an input xml,

```
<root>
  <first>
    <a>2</a>
  </first>
  <first>
    <a>3</a>
  </first>
  <first>
    <a>4</a>
  </first>
</root>
```

That should be mapped to,

```
<root>
  <a>2</a>
  <a>3</>
  <a>4</a>
</root>
```

I already have output xsd defined that is derived from second xml above but I don't see the mapping in my target because it is one level.[image]

First xml has 3 level and second one is 2 level. So I could not map the child element mapping.

Look at the `Branch` tangs in the attached image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set a [mapping](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/DataMapper+Concepts) where for each input.first -> for each input.a create a output.a.

This is doine using the element mapping controls at the top center (over the lines).

Comment: I can not do that because it is many to one mapping kinda.. First input xml has 3 hierarchy and output is 2.

Comment: In that case you could use a Rule with an xpath in the second level of the hierarchy.